# Change thumbnail on Facebook link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I link to my website on Facebook a thumbnail comes up but it is not the thumbnail I want to come up. How do I change the thumbnail. It shows the image on the object debugger

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=totelfootball.com

How do I change the image?

I have seen similar posts but want to no a simple solution for the issue? Can it be done on Facebook no coding involved?

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
2. Enter the URL following by `fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING`

**Examples:**

1. `http://www.example.com?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING`
2. `http://www.example.com?postid=1234&fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING`
3. OR visit:
   `http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.example.com/?p=3568&fbrefresh=89127348912`

I was having the same issue last night, and I got this solution from some website.

Facebook saves your cache thumbnail. The thumbnail will not change even if you delete the image from your server. But Facebook allows you to refresh by using `fbrefresh`

I hope this helps.

Comment: There is nothing special about `fbrefresh`. What you are actually doing is just changing the URL that gets requested -- it is treated as a new site. You can make any query string change for the same result.

I believe this confusion stems from an _example_ that was mentioned in the old FB blog back in early 2008.

Answer (score 9):

you can add into `<head></head>`

this tag `<link rel="image_src" href="http://URL-TO-YOUR-IMAGE" / >`

OR change `<html>` tag to

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

and add into tag `<head></head>`
this tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://URL-TO-YOUR-IMAGE" />
```

**Don`t forget** to test your link [using facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

Comment: I managed to do the second of these options, but without the xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" and the xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml". Seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose what thumbnail is displayed by adding an og:image meta tag to the HTML of totelfootball.com:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 2):

Facebook uses meta tags on the page you're sharing to determine which image, title, and description to show when posting a link. The meta tag syntax follows Facebook's [OpenGraph specification](http://ogp.me/).

The most important meta tags you need to define are:

- `<meta property="og:title" content="The title of the sharing preview" />`
- `<meta property="og:description" content="The first few lines of content below the title" />`
- `<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/your-image-1200x630px.jpg" />`

This of course only works if you have complete control over the site you’re sharing. If you’re sharing an external link (like a news article), you don’t have access to their site and therefore can’t change the meta tags. I'm using [ShareKit.io](https://www.sharekit.io), which allows you to change the title, description, and image of any link you’re sharing without having to fiddle with meta tags.

Answer (score -2):

Easier than this.

Go to the link you shared. Open it in a new tab.

Right upper corner --> Refresh Share Attachment

New thumbnail image gets fetched and you get an option to choose another.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is for the end user, not the web site owner. OP wants the right thing to appear by default.